# Razor Page Master-Detail Example

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Dears,

Lets Say i have a Parent Table and Child table (1 to many), i want to Add the Parent and all his details and his children (1 or more) in the same page, any example will be much appreciated, i'm using EF as well

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very simple demo

Model:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        Id = 1;
        Name = "Parent1";
        Age = 38;

        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child{ Id = 1, Name = "child1", Age = 6},
            new Child{ Id = 2, Name = "child2", Age = 7},
            new Child{ Id = 3, Name = "child3", Age = 10}
        };
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Parent parent { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        parent = new Parent();
    }

}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}


<h2>Parent Details</h2>
<div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.parent.Name)
</div>
<div>
    <label>Age:</label>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.parent.Age)
</div>
<div>
    <label>Children:</label>
    @foreach (var child in Model.parent.Children)
    {
        @: @child.Name
    }

</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mj, but how to create the above in a single screen ?

Comment: Hi @Allam, I am not sure what you mean, can you describe more?

Comment: Thank you Mj for your Reply, all i need is in the index page, i will insert a NEW parent details and then for example there will be a dynamic grid to insert the children (i actually dont know the count of the kids for each parent so i want it dynamic) then a submit button to save the parent then his kids and thank you in advance